# How add the new line in Textview During button action?

Tags: android

If i click the button action adding the new line Textview. If i click the button in 10 times create a  10 new line in textview and  store the 10 different data in newlines. how can i handle this problem. Anyone please help me.

Example Output is:

when click the button action first 10.00 value is displyed, then nextclickt the buuton action(2nd time) 100.00 value displyed in second new line in same textview. Then click the buton action(3rd time) 1000.00 value is displayed Third new line in same textview.

Following value display the one textview with new line
   10.00
  100.00
 1000.00
10000.00

Comment: What have you tried so far.. Add your code here.

Comment: why you want to add text 10 time in textview, for this you can use listview.

Comment: 10 is sample sir. but Its a requirement sir. Should be created a new line

Comment: Use `StringBuilder` to and append new line to that `StringBuilder` whenever button clicks, and set this `StringBuilder` to `TextView`

Comment: Following value display the one textview with new line
   10.00
  100.00
 1000.00           
10000.00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add new lines dynamically.

`textView.setText(textView.getText().toString() + "\n" );`

each time it will retrieve text from view and add `\n`

You can use append method also.

```
String text = textView.getText().toString();

YourTextView.append(text + "\n");
```

Comment: Thanks for your response sir I will try sir

Comment: Welcome, Vignesh.